# Swipe between fixed number of fragments

Tags: android

Assuming I want to have 3 tabs where each tab represents a fragment with different content, and I can both press on the tab or swipe between the tabs to change the fragments - how can I achieve that? I tried to read:
[Creating swipe views with tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral)

, and honestly as a beginner I just feel even more confused. They also provide an example of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and I believe I need the other one `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Can I see a barebone example of 3 empty fragments that you can swipe between and also have the tab indicator?

Comment: The documentation with an example is [the link you posted](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral) and sliding between fragments [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) with a sample code project [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SlidingTabsBasic). It's pretty basic, but if you take the time to walk through the example and have some more questions, feel free to reply to this answer and I'll try to answer them.

Comment: It's the same link I provided, their example uses the other adapter (for unknown amount of tabs) and I got lost there.

Comment: Did you try and let Android Studio generate a "Tabbed Activity"? It has a very basic setup with an adapter extending from FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: yeah, they suggest using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) instead.

I didn't realize you had posted that first link in your question, so I updated my answer with a couple more links that you might find helpful.

Comment: I didn't see that, I'll give it a try. Just thought that if I'll do it myself I'll learn better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two things in your layout: a `TabLayout` to hold the tabs and a `ViewPager` to hold the fragments.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you create a `FragmentPagerAdapter` that provides a different fragment for each position and a title for each fragment. This is an inner class inside your MainActivity file.

```
private class ExampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ExampleAdapter() {
        super(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return new MyFirstFragment();
            case 1: return new MySecondFragment();
            case 2: return new MyThirdFragment();

            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected position: " + position);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return "FIRST";
            case 1: return "SECOND";
            case 2: return "THIRD";

            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected position: " + position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And you wire everything up in your `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView).

This is officially provided by android.

You can follow [this](https://link.medium.com/DvGBTOOY9S) link and achieve that as per your requirements.

Let me comment if it solves your problem.

Thanks.
Happy Coding..!